# how to switch into a single database among multiple databases at run time in django?

Tags: python, database, django

how to switch into a single database among multiple databases at run time in django?

Comment: Please explain what "switch into" means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

which version of Django are you using?

1.2 supports multiple databases..for further info you can go [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/)

As for your question you can go [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database)

eg.

```
Author.objects.using('db_name').all()
```